# Is this Function Convex in a neighbourhood of $a$?

Tags: functions

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Suppose that $F$ attains a local minium in a point $a$. Is true that there exists some ball centered in $a$ such that $F$ restricted to this ball is convex?

Comment: Isn't this the definition of a local minimum?

Comment: No, the definition is: $F(a)\leq F(x)$ for all $x$ in a neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: As long as $a$ is in the interior of your domain, yes.  If you draw the tangent line $y=f(a)$, there is a neighborhood such that $f(x)\geq f(a)$; in other words, the function lies above this tangent line.   This isn't really a proof, but it's the idea.

Comment: @icurays1 Your intuition is wrong.

Comment: Interesting, I guess this wasn't as obvious as it seemed in my head. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigate the behavior of $x^2 (\sin^2\frac1x + 1)$ at $0$.